# How to allow full values (integers) only in ratingbars?

Tags: android, ratingbar

My client wants a ratingbar in one of the activities, but he doesn't want it to allow half-stars (aka float) values.
I've been google-ing around but found nothing about it. Does anybody know if it is possible to force the ratingbar to not allow half-stars?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Should be able to use `setStepSize()` and use a `1.0` to allow increments of 1 star instead of `0.5` for half stars

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setStepSize(float)) is the docs on it.

Comment: Uhm, the same answer twice... Should I accept both of them? (I am quite a rookie here :S)

Comment: They were right after each other so we were probably typing at the same time. If one was more helpful than the other at all then I would accept that one. If not, then accept the first one or whichever you want...no big deal as long as you accept one of them :)

Answer (score 58):

It can be set in the xml too, with

```
android:stepSize="1"
```

Comment: I prefer XML, as it's more declarative than Java for this.

Answer (score 18):

Try to set the Step size like this

```
ratingBar.setStepSize(1.0);
```